# How to set Send Buffer Size for sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, size, byte, buffer

I have a client socket at my server end and what I want is to set `Send buffer size` for the socket just like I set `Receive buffer size`.Any idea on how I can set it? Because while sending huge data, the socket disconnects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `socket.setsockopt()` and `SO_SNDBUF`:

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, <value>)
```

Where `<value>` is the buffer size you want to set as a Python `int`.

**Example:**

```
socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, 8192)  # Buffer size 8192
```

See: [setsockopt](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html)

Comment: what are the arguments for `setsocketopt()`. It says the take 3 arguments.

Comment: Sorry I missed an argument! Fixed :)

Comment: It's very good, But how can I read buffer at target? @JamesMills

Answer (score 6):

You can use `socket.setsockopt()`:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDBUF, size)
```